# Обработка данных на C

Tags: c

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы данные, которые отправил пользователь, обрабатывались программой на языке C,  и результат (переменная строкового типа)  отправлялся пользователю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, смотрите в сторону cgi/fastcgi. Пример реализации можно посмотреть например [здесь](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html).

Comment: о , немножко почитал вроде то что мне нужно.
вообще не знал о такой штуке , спасибо